# Laplace distribution for fitdist

Tags: r, distribution

I am trying to apply `fitdistrplus::fitdist` with Laplace distribution. I have seen the example given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29897756/how-to-define-your-own-distribution-for-fitdistr-function-in-r-with-the-help-of) post by @Ben Bolker. However, I am having a hard time figuring out the corresponding functions of the Laplace distribution and implementing them in R. So far I have tried to use `dlaplace` taken from [here](https://github.com/cran/ExtDist/blob/master/R/Laplace.R):

```
dlaplace <- function(x, mu=0, b=1, params=list(mu, b),...){
  if(!missing(params)){
    mu <- params$mu
    b <- params$b
  }
  # pdf Laplace dist Johnson et.al, Vol 2, chapter 24, p.164.
  d <- exp(-abs(x-mu)/b) / (2*b)
}
```

and run

```
laplacefit  <-  fitdistrplus::fitdist(x, "laplace", 
   start=list(mu=0,b=1), method="mme")
```

but I get

> Error in fitdistrplus::fitdist(x, "laplace", start = list(mu = 0, b =
> 1),  :    moment matching estimation needs an 'order' argument In
> addition: Warning messages: 1: In fitdistrplus::fitdist(x, "laplace",
> start = list(mu = 0, b = 1),  :   The dlaplace function should raise
> an error when names are incorrectly named 2: In
> fitdistrplus::fitdist(x, "laplace", start = list(mu = 0, b = 1),  :
> The plaplace function must be defined

Could someone provide an working example of fitting the Laplace distribution with `fitdist`?

After an useful answer I am running an example with [this file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16mKRJkg9lqp8mUExoEl5c9WwBUt8IjYI/view?usp=sharing)

```
x <- read.table("m_trg_list.txt", header=FALSE, sep=',')
x <- as.numeric(c(x))
MASS::fitdistr(x, dlaplace, start = list(b=1, mu=0))
```

but I get

> Error in stats::optim(x = c(0.00709952, 0.0072816606, 0.0076129483,
> 0.0069924397,  : non-finite finite-difference value [1]

Comment: FWIW, the Laplace distribution has a simple, closed-form MLE: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution#Statistical_inference

Comment: Where is `x`? You need to provide `x` for us to be able to help. Also, take into considerationthe comment by [@jblood94](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76605415/laplce-distrbution-for-fitdist#comment135066212_76605415) above

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is create all the functions for a distribution ie `d,p,q,r`-laplace, which is not necessary. Just pass a function instead of the distribution name to the `densfun` argument:

```
dlaplace <- function(x, mu=0, b=1){
  if(b<=0) return(NA)
  exp(-abs(x-mu)/b) / (2*b)
}
# Generate random data from laplace with `mu = 5, b = 2`
mu <- 5
b <- 2
n <- 1000
x <- rexp(n, 1/b) - rexp(n, 1/b) + mu
MASS::fitdistr(x, dlaplace, start = list(b=1, mu=0))
       b            mu    
  2.02324609   4.93653582 
 (0.06398334) (0.03169579)
```

Notice that laplace does have closed form solutions:

```
median(x)
[1] 4.936715
mean(abs(x-median(x)))
[1] 2.02316
```

Comment: Closed form solutions are useful for point estimates, but `fitdistr` might be the path of least resistance for getting standard errors of the estimates ...

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have provided a `x` as you asked in the main post. Running 
`MASS::fitdistr(x, dlaplace, start = list(b=1, mu=0))` I am getting
`Error in stats::optim(x = c(0.00709952, 0.0072816606, 0.0076129483, 0.0069924397,  : 
  non-finite finite-difference value [1]`. Any ideas.

Comment: @Thoth In case you are facing an issue, try optimizing directly using `optim` function: `optim(c(0,1), \(par)-sum(log(dlaplace(x, par[1], par[2]))))`  and see whether you get the error message. Also note that you can check as to whether the values generated are correct or not by using the closed form solutions

Comment: @BenBolker yes thats correct. Also I believe one can approximate the sds using the observed Information matrix

Comment: FWIW "non-finite finite-difference value" *usually* means (IME) that `optim()` is failing at the stage of computing the Hessian/in `optimHess`. We could do better with a [mcve] ...

Comment: @BenBolker I did an edit any comments are highly appreciated.

Comment: I have tried `MASS::fitdistr(x, dlaplace, start = list(b=1, mu=0), optim.method = "Nelder-Mead", hessian=FALSE)` as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64477268/mle-function-error-in-optimstart-f-method-method-hessian-true-n) post suggests but the same error is returned.

Comment: @Thoth `fitdistr` does not take `hessian` argument nor the method argument. Those are hard-coded into `optim` as `TRUE` and `'BFGS'` respectively and cannot be changed. Use the `optim` function directly as show in my previous comment

Comment: @Onyambu can you please provide an example wrt your comment and the [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16mKRJkg9lqp8mUExoEl5c9WwBUt8IjYI/view?pli=1) I am using? What are `par` and what is the function inside it.